# Implementing a 2D queue for Function Queue Scheduling

Tags: c, embedded, queue

I'm writing some C code to simulate the running of an embedded system. Events occur from a certain number of devices, and are given a priority 0-3. The priority of events I must serve is primarily based on device number (device 0 > device 3 > device 7) and then the priority of events served per device is based on their provided priority.

I've come to the conclusion that a 2D queue is probably the best way to implement this system. An array with for loops is considered "wasteful", and most Function Queue scheduling uses loops like while(notEmpty).

My rough plan is to create two "node" structs that look something like this:

```
struct events{
    Event curEvent; //the "node"
    struct events *next; //leads to event of lower priority
};
struct devices { //a linked list of Devices
    int deviceNumber; //the "node"
    struct devices *next;//leads to next device in order 0->max
    struct events *headEevent; //a linked list of events per device
};
```

I'm provided the number of devices to serve and the maximum number of events per device from the command line.

I suppose my question is twofold. The first is, am I on the right track? The second (and perhaps more important) is, "What's the best way to initialize this 2D queue, and the best way to enqueue events as they occur?"

Right now my initialization code is wrong, i feel:

```
curDevice = (struct device * ) malloc (sizeof (struct device));
deviceHead = curDevice;//sets head to first that's initialized
for (i = 0; i< Number_Devices; i++) {
    curDevice -> deviceNumber = i;
    curEvent = (struct event * ) malloc (sizeof (struct event));
    curDevice -> headEvent = curEvent; //sets head event to the empty curEvent
    for (j = 0; j<Q; j++) { //Q is max queue size
        newEvent = (struct event* ) malloc (sizeof struct event));
        curEvent -> next = newEvent;
        curEvent = newEvent;
    }
    new_device = (struct device * ) malloc (sizeof (struct device));
    curDevice -> next = newDevice;
    curDevice = newDevice;
}
```

I think I can discover how to enqueque on my own. I'd use a while loop to iterate through the linked list, and if the current event has higher priority than what's on the individual device's stack, I would push it on to the top.

This is a long and complicated question, so feel free to ask for any clarification you might need. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any OS, with, say, semaphores?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to have a single linked list (queue) and then insert tasks to the end. When you want to pick a next task just go over it and find a task with highest priority and remove from list.

Comment: Your suggestion would be to have a single queue with events, store their device number and priority. After the Interrupt handler runs, I'd iterate through the entire queue, and then serve the highest priority event in that single queue?

Comment: A classmate's implementation is a fixed array whose elements are linked lists leading to stored events. Maybe I'm being dumb about how FQS works. If I have events of a lower priority in a queue, and a limited space for the queue, do I remove the lowest priority event and enqueue the newer one?

Comment: @Ryanman, yes, you described exactly what I meant. When you remove element - just remove it and that's it (and free memory). Linked list is not of a fixed space, so don't worry.